# Eliminate duplicates based on 2 dates in a dataframe

Tags: r, date, duplicates, lubridate

I have this sample dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("5","5","5","5","5","5" ,"5"    ,"5","5","5","5","14","14","14","14" ,"14","14"),
                 Date1= c("22/07/2014","22/07/2014","22/07/2014"
                           ,"22/07/2014"
                           ,"22/07/2014"
                           ,"22/07/2014"
                           ,"22/07/2014"
                           ,"22/07/2014"
                           ,"22/07/2014"
                           ,"22/07/2014"
                          ,"22/07/2014"
                          ,"08/11/2016" 
                         , "08/11/2016"
                         , "08/11/2016"
                         , "08/11/2016"
                         , "08/11/2016"
                         , "08/11/2016"),
                 Date2= c("01/01/2011"
                          ,"01/08/2011"
                          ,"01/12/2010"
                          ,"10/11/2015"
                          ,"22/07/2014"
                          ,"01/01/2013"
                          ,"23/04/2014"
                          ,"01/01/2006"
                          ,"01/01/2013"
                          ,"01/10/2012"
                          ,"01/08/2012"
                          ,"14/04/2015"
                          ,"01/10/2008"
                          ,"01/10/2008"
                          ,"14/05/2015"
                          ,"11/04/2015"
                          ,"05/10/2008"),
stringsAsFactors = F)
```

where I have each ID repeated several times. I need to get a dataframe with only 1 line per ID. As you can see, each patient has only one date in column df$date1, so the condition to select 1 row per patient would be: to pick the ***closest*** date between date 1 and date 2.

How could I do that?

Thansk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `base R`, convert the 'Date' columns to `Date` class, `order` the data based on the 'ID' and the `abs`olute difference between the Date columns, subset with `duplicated` i.e. first unique row on 'ID' column

```
df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df1 <- df[with(df, order(ID, abs(as.numeric(Date1) - as.numeric(Date2)))),]
df1[!duplicated(df1$ID),]
```

-output

```
ID      Date1      Date2
15 14 2016-11-08 2015-05-14
5   5 2014-07-22 2014-07-22
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a `tidyverse` approach. I created a column called `diff_date`, which is the absolute difference between `Date1` and `Date2`. Than I filtered by each `ID` the minimum difference.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
  
  df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(.cols = starts_with("Date"),.fns = dmy),
    diff_date = abs(as.numeric(difftime(Date1,Date2)))
    ) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(diff_date == min(diff_date))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
  ID    Date1      Date2      diff_date
  <chr> <date>     <date>         <dbl>
1 5     2014-07-22 2014-07-22         0
2 14    2016-11-08 2015-05-14  47001600
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following base R code

```
unique(
  subset(
    df,
    !!ave(
      abs(as.integer(as.Date(Date2, format = "%d/%m/%Y") - as.Date(Date1, format = "%d/%m/%Y"))),
      ID,
      FUN = function(x) x == min(x)
    )
  )
)
```

and you will get

```
   ID      Date1      Date2
5   5 22/07/2014 22/07/2014
15 14 08/11/2016 14/05/2015
```